# Get SQL data type from sqlalchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to generate documentation for a database created with sqlalchemy, and want to include column SQL data types, which are dependent on the current engine. Is there any way to extract this from sqlalchemy? I tried following the `metadata.create_all(engine)` rabbit hole but quickly got lost.

Essentially what I'm after is a mapping:

```
{
    'Integer': 'INT',
    'String': 'VARCHAR',
    ...
}
```

which is specific to the current engine and takes a sqlalchemy type to a SQL data type.

Comment: Do you mean you're using the [generic types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#generic-types) and want to know what they actually compile to?

Comment: Yep, I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create/use a dialect instance and its type compiler:

```
In [18]: engine = create_engine('postgresql://sdf:sdf@localhost/sdf')

In [19]: types.Unicode().compile(dialect=engine.dialect)
Out[19]: 'VARCHAR'
```

Note that you can create relevant [`Dialect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.engine.interfaces.Dialect) subclass instances without an engine as well:

```
In [20]: from sqlalchemy.dialects import mssql

In [21]: d = mssql.dialect()

In [22]: types.Unicode(32).compile(dialect=d)
Out[22]: 'NVARCHAR(32)'
```

Comment: Perfect! This is both exactly what I was after and far simpler than I'd hoped. :)